# How to improve the evaluation score for highly imbalanced dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, bert

I have trained my BERT model(bert-base-cased) to detect toxic comments. I used the Toxic Comment Classification Challenge dataset from the Kaggle. My accuracy is 98% and the AUROC for various sub-classes is above 90%. However, my Precision, Recall, and F1 score is less. The scores are shown in the image [Evaluation Scores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpNAP.png).
The dataset is highly imbalanced. The ratio of clean comments is way higher than the toxic comments. Any suggestions to improve the evaluation scores?

Here's the final score

```
           precision  recall  f1-score   support
```

micro avg       0.61      0.85      0.71      1743  
macro avg       0.56      0.69      0.61      1743
weighted avg    0.64      0.85      0.72      1743  
samples avg     0.08      0.09      0.08      1743

Answer (score 0):

For imblanced data I recommend using [false positive ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positive_rate) instead of precision. In contrast to recall, precision is affected by the positive negative ratio, false-positive ratio (or 1 minus this number) is not affected by the data distribution, only by your model.

Comment: Thank you @Amit, I'll try using it for my evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

For imbalanced data, I suggest you use "ROC, AUC Curve" or F1 score.
Check out my article "What Is Balanced And Imbalanced Dataset?" -> https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/what-is-balance-and-imbalance-dataset-89e8d7f46bc5